# Migrate VC2008 to Eclipse CDT and map iterators

Tags: visual-studio-2008, migration, eclipse-cdt

Last weekend, i have tried to migrate my VC2008 project to Eclipse CDT.
I have resolved many problems but one subsists :

If i do this :

```
std::map<K,V>::iterator iter;
(...)
iter->first
```

The compiler says that ->first is not a member of map::iterator.
I see in VC that iter->first is defined in utility.h, in VC sdk.

Eclipse CDT includes VC files (like utility.h) at the creation of the project.
Have i missed a step ?

Thank you.